# BAD_ACCESS error when trying to read property

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal

Hi I'm trying to get started learning some metal in combination with swift on iOS. Currently I'm just trying to have the app open a custom UIView using a CAMetalLayer instead of a normal CALayer. I'm getting a BAD_ACCESS error on the following line: `self.metalLayer.device = self.device`
The following code is a subclass of UIView which is being loaded from the storyboard instead of a normal UIView. I'm following the following example which is in objective-C and I'm trying to achieve the same in swift. Kind of at a loss right now. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import Metal

class MBEMetalView: UIView {

    var device: MTLDevice

    var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer {
        return CAMetalLayer(layer: self.layer)
    }

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAMetalLayer.self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)


        self.metalLayer.device = self.device
        self.metalLayer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm

    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        self.redraw()
    }

    func redraw() {
        var drawable: CAMetalDrawable? = self.metalLayer.nextDrawable()
        var texture: MTLTexture? = drawable?.texture

        var passDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor.self()
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadAction.Clear
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreAction.Store
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor.init(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue = self.device.newCommandQueue()

        var commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()

        var commandEncoder: MTLCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(passDescriptor)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

@alex_p showed me that my readonly computable function for metalLayer gave me a new CAMetalLayer every time I called it so I've changed my code but now I get the following SIGABRT error 
`/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-55.1.1/ToolsLayers/Debug/MTLDebugDevice.mm:629: failed assertion "iosurface must not be nil."` on the following line: `var drawable: CAMetalDrawable? = self.metalLayer.nextDrawable()`

My current code is:

```
import UIKit
import Metal

class MBEMetalView: UIView {

    var device: MTLDevice? = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAMetalLayer.self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.commandQueue = self.device!.newCommandQueue()

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.metalLayer.device = self.device
        self.metalLayer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm

    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        self.redraw()
    }

    func redraw() {
        var drawable: CAMetalDrawable? = self.metalLayer.nextDrawable()
        let texture: MTLTexture? = drawable!.texture

        let passDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor.self()
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadAction.Clear
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreAction.Store
        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor.init(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()

        let commandEncoder: MTLCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(passDescriptor)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check if ```self.metalLayer.device``` is not nil?

Comment: you're doing a very strange thing in this place `var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer {
        return CAMetalLayer(layer: self.layer)
    }`, in fact every time you return a pointer to the new object when accessing the variable, it basically can not work properly in your case

Comment: @Tobonaut whenever I try to do that I also get a BAD_ACCESS error. But it does have to do something with that statement because whenever I try to assign a value to metalLayer.device I get the error.

Comment: @alex_p What do you think is incorrect about the method I use? It's just a computable readonly swift function which casts the normal CALayer to a CAMetalLayer.

Comment: This is computed propertie that every time create the reference to new `CAMetalLayer` object (that created with your `layer`)  when you `get` it. Here `self.metalLayer.device = self.device` for example it return reference to one `CAMetalLayer` object and here `self.metalLayer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm` it return reference to onother `CAMetalLayer` object and you have not kept the reference to the previous object. And when you next time call it, it return the new reference to new `CAMetalLayer` object with your `layer` but without `self.device` and `MTLPixelFormat.BGRA8Unorm`

Comment: @alex_p Ah ok I understand now! thanks I have rewritten part of the code now but I get a different error now. Which I also don't quite understand. I'll add it to my original post.